# On demand Publish on Meteor?

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

Is there a way to publish updates to a collection only on demand? (e.g. send updates only every 5 seconds?)

I am publishing a leaderboard, which shows the the top 50 players (have the most points) in a game. Updates to users' points happen frequently, so that the leaderboard changes very often (every 1-5 seconds). Every minute or so, the server updates points for ~100 user in a forEach loop. The problem is that the publish methods start updating right away, before all the 100 elements have been updated. This creates a painful performance issue (publishing updates to all users multiple times)...

Is there a way to hold the publish until all the updates are done? Or a way to update the published data only every 5 seconds instead of immediately?

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Sounds similar to an article I read recently: http://tomkelsey.co.uk/reining-in-the-reactivity-with-meteor/ maybe that will help :)

Comment: After reading your question a second time, your premise is wrong. You first ask how to do it "on demand" (from the client), then you give as an example "every 5 seconds", which is controlled by the server. Please narrow down your question to a **single, precise** issue.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom publication and take control!

```
var pubsHandlers = [];

Meteor.publish('totalScore', function() {
  this.added('someClientCollection', 'totalScoreId', {
    totalScore : someGetTotalScoreFunction()
  });
  pubsHandlers.push(this); //Maaaaybe not the cleanest thing to do.
  this.ready();
});

Meteor.setInterval(function updateScores() {
  var newTotalScore = somegetTotalScoreFunction()
  pubsHandlers.forEach(function(pubHandler) {
    pubHandler.changed('someClientCollection', 'totalScoreId', {
      totalScore : newTotalScore
  });
}, 5000); //Each 5 seconds, update everyone
```

So here's what's happening:

1. Publishing in a custom way, by [adding](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/publish_added) a document to our publication,
2. Remembering the publication handler for further updates,
3. At a later time (here in an [interval](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_setinterval)), use the remembered handlers to [update](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/publish_changed) the document.

The main benefit is to keep the server in full control of the publication and its updates.
The main drawback is the use of `push(this)`. It's not necessarily bad but it looks so damn hideous...

Comment: I first saw this pattern in a Meteor Devshop video. If you happen to know which video it was, feel free to add the link in a comment or in an edit.

Answer (score 0):

The article http://tomkelsey.co.uk/reining-in-the-reactivity-with-meteor/ discusses this exact issue, the author "used a combination of Meteor methods and the usual publication/subscription approach. A simplified example is set out below.

Within the onCreated method of the homepage I request a sorted array of item _ids from the server and save them into a session variable called itemIds:

```
Meteor.call('getItemIds', function(err, res) {   
   Session.set('itemIds', res);
});
```

On the server, the method is defined as:

```
Meteor.methods({
   getItemIds: function() {
    return Items.find({}, {fields: {_id: 1}, sort: 
    {rank:1}}).fetch();
  }
});
```

I then watch for any changes to the itemIds session variable and (re)subscribe accordingly:

```
var self = this;
self.autorun(function() {
    self.subscribe('itemsById', Session.get('itemIds'));
});
```

On the server, the publication looks like this:

```
Meteor.publish('itemsById', function(itemIds) {
    return Items.find({}, {_id: {$in: itemIds}});
});
```

My template iterates over the itemIds array rather than the Items collection cursor. This means the order of items remains static.

For each _id within itemIds I can do an Items.find(_id) – the data will be in our client-side Items collection courtesy of our itemsById subscription.

Voila we have a list of reactive items that will retain its order until the page is refreshed."

Sound like it could be adapted for you :)